# .htaccess rewrite and redirect two types of urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to create clean URL with .htacces rewrite. I have two types of urls:

1. site.com/page.php?page=something
2. site.com/something.php

I need them both to be just site.com/something, with redirect from ugly  to pretty url. So now I have the following rules, which don't work together, and I totally stuck with the redirect.

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# page.php?page=about to about
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?$ /page.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

# something.php to something
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There server can tell which to use by inspecting the `%{QUERY_STRING}` using a `RewriteCond` on the first rule.

Comment: @PanamaJack the rule like `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.php?$ /page.php?page=$1 [NC]` doesn't work for the same reason? I can rewrite /page.php?page=something to something.html but not to something.php

Comment: @PanamaJack No worries, just trying to help clarify, I initially thought the same as you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that are incorrect in your example:

- You cannot inspect the query string in a `RewriteRule`, only in a `RewriteCond`
- Your `RewriteRule` lines are backwards - the first part is a regular expression match of the URL and the second is what you want it to be.
- You will need to have an `[R]` rule as part of the rewrite to perform a redirect, otherwise it will just "rewrite" the URL the server sees and not change the actual URL.

Here is an example of your first rewrite, redirecting `/page.php?page=foo` to `/foo`. You first need a `RewriteCond` to inspect the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable to see if it has `page=...` in it. We can use the character match `([^&]*)` to grab all of the characters that are not an ampersand and store in a matching group. Next we perform a `RewriteRule` for `page.php` (note that we don't need the leading `/` because of the `RewriteBase` and that the `.` is escaped). If there is a match here, you want to redirect to the matching group from the `RewriteCond` - it is referred to with a `%1` rather than a `$1` like it would if it were from the `RewriteRule`. You will also want to append a `?` to the end of your redirect which tells Apache to drop the query string so you don't end up with `/foo?page=foo`. Finally you will need `[R=301]` to perform a redirect with an HTTP status code of 301. The `[L]` indicates that that this is the **L**ast rule you want to process if there is a match.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# page.php?page=about to about
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule page\.php /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Your second rewrite is closer, but as in the first the logic is backwards. You want the first part to match `*.php` and then the second to indicate the redirect to `/$1`. Again you will need the `[R-301]` for the redirect.

```
# something.php to something
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

You can test this out on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.

Using `http://example.com/page.php?page=foo`, redirects to `http://example.com/foo`

```
1       RewriteEngine On    
2       RewriteBase /   
3       # page.php?page=about to about  
4       RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]*) [NC]   
            This condition was met
5       RewriteRule page\.php /%1? [R=301,L]    
            This rule was met, the new url is http://example.com/foo    
            Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. 
            A redirect will be made with status code 301
```

Using `http://example.com/foo.php` redirect to `http://example.com/foo`

```
1       RewriteEngine On    
2       RewriteBase /   
3       # page.php?page=about to about  
4       RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]*) [NC]   
            This condition was not met
5       RewriteRule page\.php /%1? [R=301,L]    
            This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met
6       # something.php to something    
7       RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]    
            This rule was met, the new url is http://example.com/foo    
            Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. 
            A redirect will be made with status code 301
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the OP's issue. There are 2 different formats that are trying to be made into clean URL's. The problem is you can't have both. There is nothing wrong with the OP's code individually, Just can't use both rules together which is what they want.

Comment: @PanamaJack You absolutely can have both, check out my answer. The first rule has a `RewriteCond` and inspects the querystring for `page=`. If there is a match, it redirects. If there isn't a match the next rule is processed and redirects to the "clean" url using just the PHP filename. You would obviously need additional rules to then process the clean URLS, but the redirects work fine :)

Comment: @doublesharp Thank you, the redirects are really working fine :)

Comment: @doublesharp, Then maybe I misunderstood what was being asked. Because I'm assuming the question using `www.example.com/something` in the browser, not the `real` URL's. So if that's the case, the first rule in the OP's example will always run before the 2nd rule.

Comment: @PanamaJack If you are looking at the examples in the question then you would be correct, but like I mentioned in my answer, they are backwards for what the OP is trying to do. The desire is to redirect from "ugly" URLs (with the php filename in them) to "clean" URLs like `/about`. There would be additional rules to then pass `/about` through `index.php` or something similar to actually process the request.

Comment: @doublesharp yes I see that part of the requirement now which I missed, which I would actually have used `THE_REQUEST` instead of query string for that but either way will work, however it still won't fix the way I mentioned regardless if fixing the issue of ugly to clean.

Comment: @Irina glad to see it's working for you. If this solved your problem would you mind marking it as the answer? Thanks!